# Не запускается webStorm на Mac OS

Tags: веб-программирование, macos, mac, webstorm

не запускается WebStorm на Mac OS

в настройках Edit Custom VM Options 
поменял javaagent как поменять его обратно

пытался переустанавливать ничего

может где-то хранятся остатки, чтобы снести полностью, а может просто остался файл и я смогу его изменить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто удалите файл `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1/webstorm.vmoptions` (или `~/Library/Preferences/WebStorm<номер версии>/webstorm.vmoptions`, если вы используете версию меньше 2020.1)

Comment: Таких файлов и папок нет

Comment: какую версию IDE вы используете?

Comment: WebStorm 2020.1.2

Comment: в таком случае у вас точно дожна быть папка `~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1`. см. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Простите, такой папки нету, я устанавливал WebStorm кажется не удалил строчку с прежним javaagent и позже попытался удалить папку и случайно очистить корзину сначала показывал ошибку когда папка существовала, а после очистки корзины перестал вообще подавать признаки жизни

Comment: только что попробовал установить 2019 версию запустилась обновился до 2020 снова не запускается

Comment: удалось запустить приложение с ошибкой вот лог https://justpaste.it/6i581

Comment: Удалось, перекинуть файлы с другого макбука с установленным WebStorm папки
~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1

И изменить webstorm.vmoptions с настройками из установленной версии ToolBox Jetbrains
)) запутано но если проще, просто установить из ToolBox Jetbrains сборку в отдельную папку (сам создает в User/ваш_учетная запись/Apps/Jetbrains/) и оттуда достать vmoptions скопировать в ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/WebStorm2020.1

Comment: Совет выше мне помог, спасибо)
Для тех, кто долго страдал (как это было со мной), Library, о которой говорится, отображается только при зажатом option в переходе (меню сверху). Дальше просто ищете через поиск файндера файлы (следите за папкой, в которой происходит поиск) и удаляете нужный файл.